# Why does \huge have to be put inside curly brackets?

Tags: formatting, fontsize

Why does the `\huge` command go inside the brackets? Wouldn't it be more consistent doing

```
\huge{my huge text}
```

?

Comment: As Werner says, `\huge` is not a command with arguments, it is a declaration, which have certain scoping rules. It's a different approach. Declarations like `\huge` can apply to multiple paragraphs of text, for example, and across environments (depending on where they used), or entirely within an environment, but for the whole course of the environment. This makes them useful in definitions (although you have to be careful when defining your own commands and using declarations)

Comment: By the way, something like `\textbf{foo}` has the counterpart declaration `{\bfseries foo}`, so it's really not a matter of inconsistency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all macros take arguments. In this case, `\huge` (and other font-setting macros) don't take an argument. They are considered a *declaration* or a *switch*, changing the font(size) from that point onward. If the switch it not contained in a group (brackets), it'll cause unexpected results.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\texthuge}[1]{{\huge #1}}
\begin{document}
\normalsize Here is some \huge{huge} text. \par
\normalsize Here is some {\huge huge} text. \par
\normalsize Here is some \texthuge{huge} text.
\end{document}
```

Note how the first sentence has `huge text` set in `\huge`, even though it seems like `\huge` should only apply to `huge`. The second sentence places the declaration within a group, meaning it doesn't survive outside of it, limiting the scope. The last sentence converts `\huge` into a macro that takes an argument, still limiting the scope to a group.

Comment: Note also how its friend, the `\normalsize` switch resets the font size at the beginning of each new line

Comment: `\DeclareTextFontCommand\texthuge{\huge}` is the provided syntax to create new macrost that behave exactly like that.